# Date compares in Rails SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this query in Rails (mysql database).

```
planSubscriptions = PlanSubscription.find_by_sql(["SELECT ps.*
     FROM plan_subscriptions ps, plans p, states s
     WHERE p.name = 'Unlimitted'
     AND s.name = 'Confirmed' 
     AND p.id = ps.plan_id 
     AND s.id = ps.state_id
     AND date_format(ps.updated_at + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-%d') <= date_format(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')"])
```

It´s not working because malformed format string - %Y

I need to compare only the date (not the times). What is the right syntax?

Comment: Try [EXTRACT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is perfectly capable of comparing date values directly:

```
... (DATE(ps.updated_at + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < curdate())
```